# Erratic action of NSToolbarItem

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton, nstask, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I am using toolbar buttons to control a simple NSTask. The code below works as expected when the IBAction is given by regular buttons, but produces artifacts when it is given by an NSToolbarItem. More precisely, the run button does not get disabled. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
import Cocoa

class Document: NSDocument {

    override var windowNibName: String? {
        return "Document"
    }

    @IBOutlet var runButtonOutlet: NSToolbarItem! // works for NSButton 

    @IBAction func runButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        runTask()
        runButtonOutlet.enabled = false
    }
    @IBAction func quitButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        bigTask.terminate()
        runButtonOutlet.enabled = true
    }

    var bigTask = NSTask()

    func runTask () {
        let task = NSTask()
        bigTask = task
        task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/say"
        task.arguments = ["say something"]
        task.terminationHandler = {
            task in
            self.runButtonOutlet.enabled = true
        }
        task.launch()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the toolbar hierarchy and add a screenshot, please?

Comment: Is autovalidates of the toolbar items switched off?